# render soap data with washout gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins

```
I am trying to render a ruby hash in soap format 
render :soap => {:notification_response => {:ack => true}}

    The generated xml is like 
<notification_response>{"ack"=>"false"}</notification_response>
```

I tried to eliminate ruby hash from the generated resposne but not succeed.

```
    How to generate xml as 
<notification_response><ack>false</ack></notification_response>
```

Answer (score 0):

`render :soap => {:notification_response => {:ack => true}.to_xml}`